# How to Join Three Tables with Count Function to Return Zero Results Too?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have this query, with three tables (invoices, customer_addresses, countries), I want to return the number of sales for each country, some countries don't have sales, so I want to return zero as sales_count other than exclude them from the results.

```
SELECT c.name,c.iso_code,c.id as country_id, COUNT(*) as sales_count ,SUM(a.total_due) as gross
        FROM `invoices` a
            JOIN `customer_addresses` b
            ON b.`customer_id` = a.`customer_id`
            JOIN `countries` c
            ON c.`id` = b.`country_id`
        WHERE  a.`status` = 'Paid' AND a.`deleted` ='No'
        GROUP BY c.name
```

**Sample Data:**

**Invoices**

```
id   | total_due | customer_id
1    |    25     |      5
2    |    45     |      7
```

**customer_addresses**

```
id |    address    | customer_id | country_id
5  |  some address | 1           |    3
7  |  some address | 2           |    4
```

**countries**

```
id |       name     | iso_code 
3  | USA            | US
4  | United Kingdom | UK
5  | France         | Fr
```

Comment: It's always wise to include sample data and desired results when asking sql query questions. Should a sale from a customer who has addresses in multiple countries be counted towards each country?

Comment: @popovitsj I added sample data, as you can see "France" has no reference in the "customer_addresses" table, so my query didn't return it with the results, I want to include France too, with sales_count = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `right join` instead of an `(inner) join`, but it is not used much and it is generally considered to be poorly readable.

So instead, you could use a `left join` for the tables and make `country` the first table. With a `left join`, you still get a result even when there is no matching row in the joined table. The call to `count` is slightly altered too. `count(*)` would return just the row count, so it would return `1` for countries without invoice. `count(invoice_id)` only counts those rows where `invoice_id is not null`, so that will return `0` for countries that have no sales.

```
SELECT 
  c.name, c.iso_code, c.id as country_id, 
  COUNT(a.invoice_id) as sales_count,
  SUM(a.total_due) as gross
FROM 
  `countries` c
  LEFT JOIN `customer_addresses` b
    ON c.`id` = b.`country_id`
  LEFT JOIN `invoices` a
    ON b.`customer_id` = a.`customer_id`
    AND a.`status` = 'Paid' 
    AND a.`deleted` ='No'
GROUP BY c.name
```

Comment: I just tried it, unfortunately it didn't work, still not returning the countries with zero sales.

Comment: You are right. I made a silly mistake. The conditions that were in the WHERE clause also should be in the join, otherwise those countries are still excluded. I fixed the query now.